# How to select an entire string in android studio

Tags: android-studio

How can i get whole texts selected under string "" in android studio ?
I tried selecting it with double click but not done, also tried by triple click but it selected the whole line of code.
Sample code is given below -

```
listDataHeader.add("Principle of Effective Stress and related phenomena");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listDataHeader.add("Principle of Effective Stress and related phenomena");
```

Place your pointer before " and double mouse click will do this job.